# Why wont my 'background' render?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm having this problem in Blender that it is only loading the text, I am very new to this and don't know why it is cutting out what is even in the camera view and making it black. If you could help me, I would really appreciate it.

It's only rendering 'Kenny Miller" and not the green/black back:

[[image: ]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Empties have no geometry

You are using an **Empty object** to display the image (you can that from the icon in the outliner), but as stated by [the manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/empties.html#empties):

> The “Empty” is a null object. It contains **no real Geometry**, [...]

This means that the object has no faces, no materials, so the engine has nothing to render. What you see in the viewport is just a "gizmo", useful to work with but has no influence on the rendered image.

The Image-Empties can be useful to quickly put some movable references in the scene. If you want to render the image, I would suggest to use the [Images as plane](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images) add-on, that starting from an image create a true object in the scene.